# WPF Tabcontrol DataTemplate and child user control initialization

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a view with a TabControl and the content of each tab is defined as a Resource in TabControl.Resources. In this content, I have a user control which basically contains a datagrid.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabs}"
            SelectionChanged="TabSelected">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type uc:Tab}">
            <uc:MyUserControlWithDatagrid />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

To my surprise, I notice that even if I have multiple tab items, I only enter once in MyUserControlWithDatagrid's constructor. I am guessing that it is "shared" between all tab items?

If that is correct, how can I make it so that a usercontrol instance is created for each tab item?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization) about the virtualization of tabs.

You can download the code samples from [here](https://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/PersistentTabControl/).

The solution proposed enables you to define a custom template:

```
<TabControl ikriv:TabContent.IsCached="True">
    <ikriv:TabContent.Template>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- custom content template goes here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ikriv:TabContent.Template>
</TabControl>
```